# What are services in OS X Server?

Tags: osx-server

I've just installed `OS X Server`. What are services?

[image]

What do I enable them for? Lets consider `Xcode` and `Messages`. How can I use it?

Comment: I don't really know how to flag this question.

Comment: :-) think it up...

Comment: That's like asking "What's the purpose of the two levers attached to the bicycle handlebar" **after** unintentionally racing downhill with a mountain bike. ;-)

Comment: ;-) you are right... Better later than never ;-)

Comment: This fails to show any research per [ask] - also, one question per question please. Even asking what to do with Xcode server is quite broad if you could write a chapter in a book on it. At best, use the help menu to show how you can't use the documentation that ships with server app answer a more focused question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Services are the different jobs that the server can do for you and anyone else who uses the server (assuming they have their own computer and a valid password to the server). Many/most of the Services are intended to help groups of people work together. Many/most of the Services can be set up so that people with different OS can work together.

Usually, you won't need or enable all of them but it's worth considering what you might make good use of and experimenting with some of them.

Below is a list of descriptions of the Services that I've shamelessly plagiarized from the book: **OS X Server Essentials 10.10 by Arek Dreyer & Ben Greisler** (I have a hard copy but you can buy it via itunes and other fine stores - https://itunes.apple.com/book/os-x-server-essentials-10.10/).

**Caching** - speed up the download of software from Apple

**Calendar** - share calendars, book resources like meeting rooms, projectors, etc

**Contacts** - share Contacts information

**Filesharing** - share files. These mount like hard drives on the user's computer.

**Mail** - provide email service (needs a domain name, obviously)

**Messages** - used to be ichat. Think of it like Skype. Users can text each other, video conference, etc.

**Profile Manager** - manage the different Apple devices you are responsible for from the server

**Time Machine** - backup the different Macs on your network to the server

**VPN** - users not physically at the same location as the server can connect to it over the internet and be treated as if they are physically there (so they can use printers, other services, etc).

**Websites** - a web server

**Wiki** - a web site that can be easily edited with free-form information. Think Wikipedia but not as sophisticated. Each user can have their own wiki.

**Xcode** - allows developers of Xcode projects to share code and collaboratively build something